# I got userinfo, how get user posts from wall?

Tags: java, android, vk, vk-sdk

I started work with **Vkontakte android SDK**, and doing it well). I made authorization, and got userFirstName, userLastName and userPhoto. But I have no idea how get user wall, or user posts from user wall. It should be similar, and I see response #2 in logcat, but I don't really know how parse it???

```
        //Prepare request for userName and photo
        final VKRequest request1 = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_100, contacts"));
        //Prepare request for userWall
        final VKRequest request2 = VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID));

        //Parallel executing requests
        VKBatchRequest batch = new VKBatchRequest(request1, request2);
        batch.executeWithListener(new VKBatchRequest.VKBatchRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse[] responses) {
                super.onComplete(responses);
                //Work with responses
                //*****
                //UserName and photo response
                //*****
                VKApiUserFull user = ((VKList<VKApiUserFull>) responses[0].parsedModel).get(0);
                Ion.with(ivUserPhoto).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .load(user.photo_100);
                tvUserName.setText(user.first_name + " " + user.last_name);
                //********
                //Wall response similar sa userResponse...
                //********
                VKApiPost mPost = ((VKList<VKApiPost>) responses[1].parsedModel).get(0);
                Log.e("post name", mPost.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                //Error;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here right code, tnx **Dreddik** <-- vk android sdk developer.

```
VKRequest request2 = VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, VKSdk.getAccessToken().userId, VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1));

request2.executeWithListener(new VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onError(VKError error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        VKList<VKApiPost> posts = (VKList<VKApiPost>) response.parsedModel;
        VKApiPost post = posts.get(0);
        Log.d("Post:", post.toString());
    }
});
```